# Scraping multiple pages in Steam with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My goal is to scrape Action games' information, such as name of game, tags, prices.
Used libraries are requests, beautifulsoup.
URL : https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Action/#p=0&tab=ConcurrentUsers

I managed to code it up for the first page and then I tried to scrape 15 pages.
My plan was that when I replace the "/Action/#p=0" with "/Action/#p=1" in the url and send a get request, I would receive the html response with the games from next page.
For some reason this did not work as even if I try with "#p=15", I get the html for the first page. Then I inspected the page elements (1,2,3,4..) but they do not contain any links.
Next, I started looking in "Inspect > Network tab" to check if I can intercept any link that resembles the html of the next page and I found it - upon inspection it did contain the games from the next page.
URL for second page : https://store.steampowered.com/contenthub/querypaginated/tags/ConcurrentUsers/render/?query=&start=15&count=15&cc=BG&l=english&v=4&tag=Action&tagid=19

The page number 2 in the URL where the number is the "=&start" value/15.
Unfortunately, the content is unusable as the hierarchies of the tags are messed up.
For example:

```
           <span class="top_tag">
            FPS
           </span>
           <span class="top_tag">
            , Shooter
           </span>
```

Would be:

```
       <span class='\"top_tag\"'>
        FPS&lt;\/span&gt;
        <span class='\"top_tag\"'>
         , Shooter&lt;\/span&gt;
```

The second span class is the child of the first, where it should be its sibling.
Both examples are decoded using prettify soup method with utf-8.

Is there a better way to do this? I am aware I can do it using regex or selenium, but I wonder if there is a way to do this task with beautifulsoup and requests.

Comment: You'd probably be a lot better off either using the official [Steam Web API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview) or a Python Steam module like [`steam`](https://pypi.org/project/steam/).

Comment: @MattDMo I took a look for an API before I started, but it is not mentioned in the steam page at the footer. Thanks, I'll look harder next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content that the server responds is in Json format, so use `.json()` method to parse it. For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://store.steampowered.com/contenthub/querypaginated/tags/ConcurrentUsers/render/"

params = {
    "query": "",
    "start": 0,
    "count": 15,
    "cc": "US",
    "l": "english",
    "v": "4",
    "tag": "Action",
    "tagid": "19",
}


for page in range(5):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    params["start"] = 15 * page
    data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["results_html"], "html.parser")
    for item in soup.select(".tab_item_content"):
        print(
            "{:<40} {}".format(
                item.select_one(".tab_item_name").text,
                item.select_one(".tab_item_top_tags").text,
            )
        )
```

Prints:

```
Counter-Strike: Global Offensive         FPS, Shooter, Multiplayer, Competitive
Grand Theft Auto V                       Open World, Action, Multiplayer, Automobile Sim
Lost Ark                                 MMORPG, Free to Play, Action RPG, Hack and Slash
Apex Legends™                            Free to Play, Battle Royale, Multiplayer, Shooter
PUBG: BATTLEGROUNDS                      Survival, Shooter, Multiplayer, Battle Royale
Dota 2                                   Free to Play, MOBA, Multiplayer, Strategy
ELDEN RING                               Souls-like, Relaxing, Dark Fantasy, RPG
Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six® Siege          FPS, Hero Shooter, Multiplayer, Tactical
Vampire Survivors                        Action Roguelike, Pixel Graphics, Bullet Hell, Casual
NARAKA: BLADEPOINT                       Battle Royale, Sexual Content, Multiplayer, Martial Arts
Warframe                                 Free to Play, Action RPG, RPG, Action
Destiny 2                                Free to Play, Open World, Looter Shooter, FPS
Wallpaper Engine                         Mature, Utilities, Software, Anime
Rust                                     Survival, Crafting, Multiplayer, Open World
Dead by Daylight                         Horror, Survival Horror, Multiplayer, Online Co-Op
Brawlhalla                               Free to Play, Multiplayer, Fighting, Casual
Dread Hunger                             Multiplayer, Survival, Online Co-Op, Social Deduction
Stumble Guys                             Action, Casual, 3D, 3D Platformer
ARK: Survival Evolved                    Open World Survival Craft, Survival, Open World, Multiplayer
LEGO® Star Wars™: The Skywalker Saga     LEGO, Adventure, Open World, Multiplayer

...and so on.
```